# Eclipse: Installed Java 8 - Could not find or load main class

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I have installed Java 8 and want use it in new java project at Eclipse, but every time when I create main class, I get

> Error" Could not find or load main class

When I try to make new project with default JavaSE-1.7, which was configured at Eclipse, there is no problem and it runs.

Someone got any idea, wheres problem? If theres problem at Eclipse or in installed Java 8 etc.? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "Clean"ing your workspace and rebuilding all projects?

Comment: This is a message that happens when you create the class or when you try to do something with it like Run it?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, i tried that.

Comment: @nitind That message happens when I try Run it.

Comment: Very hard to diagnose from a distance. Could you post a screenshot of the preferences page listing the JREs maybe?

Comment: Just some ideas. Make 200% sure that you actually have Java 8, that you configured it as Java 8 in Eclipse, and that the project's compliance level is also set to Java 8. Also, make sure that you are using Eclipse Luna or newer; Eclipse Kepler and older has no integrated Java 8 support.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Window>preferences>java>Installed JREs

Now change your JRE location(if any) by clicking Edit button, or add new JRE location by clicking add button. Your location of JRE may be "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40", but first make sure for correct JRE location.

Comment: [link](http://pasteboard.co/11NRggNNG.png) I think that there isnt problem. That location is correct, but when I am creating new project and select "Use default JRE (currently 'java-8-oracle')" it writes down "The current workspace uses a 1.4 JRE with compiler compliance level 1.8", but at settings I got only compliance level 1.7.

Comment: If 1.8 isn't even an option, **you're using an old build that predates 1.8 and may not launch 1.8 properly.**

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, Probably you are trying to run a class as java application that does not have a main method or the byte code is not generated for the class, you will have to try building the class.

Comment: Nope, as i said, when i try create project with JavaSE-1.7 there is no problem. But when i create project in same way, just with Java 8, I got this error.